# Docker specific domain to a specific container

Tags: linux, wordpress, docker, containers

I want to create many WordPress containers, but only on one VPS machine. Is there a possibility to build something that will work like this: "Okay, that request comes from example.com, so I will redirect connection to docker container 1", another example: "Okay, that request comes from example2.com, so I will redirect connection to docker container 2".
I want to have assigned specific domain to a specific docker container. Can it be done, if yes, how?

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need reverse proxy (e.g. nginx, traefik...) which will route requests to certain container.
If you have not  experience in configuring reverse proxy, traefik will be easier.
High-level steps:

1. configure and run traefik
2. add `labels` section to wp service in `docker-compose.yml`
3. add `.env` for wp and run via `docker-compose` or `docker swarm`
4. repeat step 3 for new wp instances (with new domains)

Good instructions how to do it with traefik: [via docker-compose](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-traefik-v2-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-docker-containers-on-ubuntu-20-04), [via docker swarm](https://dockerswarm.rocks/traefik/)